# Add php composer packages to my git repository

Tags: php, git-submodules, composer-php

I've installed composer and added some packages via 'composer install'. It installed them under "my_project\vendor" path but some of the packages were cloned using git, so when I committed "my_project", those cloned packages were ignored.

The problem is that when other developers are cloning "my_project", they are missing the packages that were ignored. Is there a way to automatically add the packages to "my_project" so other developers will fetch them from me?

I think this should be done using submodules, but I don't know how to automatically add every new package from composer as a submodule to my project.

Comment: `they are missing the packages that were ignored` - sounds about right. You probably need to manually add them to the repository.

Comment: you mean manually add them as git submodules, so this won't happen again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Preface: Jordi - I love composer, keep up the great work, and if I'm mistaken on any of this let me know and I'll both update my workflow and edit the post :D

---

Unfortunately this isn't the "general recommendation" depending on who you ask, it's by far a developer-only perspective.  And the caveats to using the practice prescribed in the composer FAQ have many more considerations than I can cover here.  So I'll leave a couple major points for the consideration of others.

By @Seldaek's [own admission](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/270) composer isn't really 100% stable, far better from a year ago, but still a [very active project](https://github.com/composer/composer/graphs) regardless.  So relying on composer to implement an identical environment on a dev server vs staging server vs production server wouldn't be a general recommendation from any QA / Deployment group.  This is not meant as a slight to Jordi, but rather an expression of the maticulous nature of QA peoples.

From the FAQ, it states when merging vendor libs into your own repository you should:

> Limit yourself to installing tagged releases (no dev versions)

However if you use composer to manage your CI or automated deployments, the same constraint would apply - only **more so** - because deploying a master or dev tag to your production environment could be a **very** different package than what you tested in staging only a day or even an hour ago.

Even outside of changes introduced in third party libs (which would be solved by using only tagged versions regardless of dev or production deployments) unless you can rely on composer doing the exact same thing every time, you'll risk introducing bugs into production.  This is not really a risk-case I would concern myself with, but then again I'm a developer too ;)  But issues can result from [simple changes like this](http://seld.be/notes/composer-an-update-on-require-dev) where unless you maintain the exact same version of composer.phar on all environments, you could really muck up a staging or production server.

The other major issue I have is really related to all of the points listed under this heading:

> While it can be tempting to commit it in some environment, it leads to a few problems:

I don't see the consequences as problems, but instead benefits! A large vcs repository isn't that big of a deal in modern high bandwidth environments.  And unless you are using a very active vendor lib, your diffs won't be that big either.  Even if they were big, git/hg/dvcs systems are all capable of re-using chunks, compressing chunks and keeping all your ducks in a row.  But more so, they are an alert to the developer when changes are introduced to those packages, and `diff -w` is a great summary view of the total changesets, **especially** if you are on dev/master tags.

> Duplication of the history of all your dependencies in your own VCS.

This is worded a little incorrectly, it won't duplicate the entire commit history of the vendor lib, just a single commit (your commit) covering the full delta between now and the last time you ran a composer update resulting in changes.  You're probably not updating all of your libs every time you update, even if you don't specify individual packages.  And if you did accidentally update a vendor lib, you can easily revert, whereas if you did so on a dev/master tag and it broke your environment, you'd have to figure out what version you were previously using and specify the tag in composer.json, and update again to revert it.  `git checkout /vendor/3rdpartylib --force` just seems easier to me.

> Adding dependencies installed via git to a git repo will show them as submodules. This is problematic because they are not real submodules, and you will run into issues.

Ideally, composer would give you a config option.  It could automatically delete the .git directory from git pulls, and automatically rm the directory (or temporarily mv it) before updating a lib, when and only when an updated version exists.  And doing so would be far more reliable than leaving that manual process up to individual developers.  There are an equal number of reasons to have vendor libs integrated into your version control repo so the choice really depends on the details of your situation.

The biggest reason for versioning all of your files is being able to reliably deploy the exact package you tested in development to staging to production, a key purpose of vcs and automated deployments to begin with.  Unless you configure your development environment to use specific tags for every package and you version control your composer.phar you should not rely on composer to deploy your software.

Comment: One thing you seem to completely ignore in this whole description is the composer.lock file. This one should be committed, and it guarantees that you will have the exact same version installed everywhere you run composer **install**. Even dev versions will be locked to the specific commit they were updated to when you last ran **update**. This invalidates most reasons to commit vendors I think.

Comment: @Seldaek what if Composer is simply unavailable at a time of deployment?

Comment: @Meglio "Composer" is a CLI tool, it can't really be unavailable. Packagist.org is used only for update, not for install, so if you use install on deploy you're safe there. GitHub and co are used to download packages at install, so that needs to be available. And for that we offer Private Packagist (https://packagist.com/) which mirrors archives to give you more reliability and it also speeds up updates as a bonus.

Answer (score 13):

You should ideally just add vendor/ to your .gitignore, and then every developer of the project would run composer install to get the vendors on his setup.

You can read the [FAQ entry](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) on commiting vendors for more details.

Comment: ok, thanx, I should follow "the general recommendation" then.

Comment: @Seldaek: how do you manage automated deployment to staging and production in that case? Is the composer.lock file combined with a git post-update hook your solution of choice?

Comment: @BryanAgee my solution of choice is a deploy script that "builds" a project first, which includes running `composer install`. And then puts this built directory in production (by moving a symlink or swappings dirs). Any "in-line" deployment method that acts on the live source will mean you have a few seconds of instability and could end up in a broken state without easy way to rollback.